# Track all process activity in real or near real time on Linux

Tags: networking, process, authentication, logging

I want to track the activity of processes.

For processes, forks, file access, etc. should be tracked.
Also files, data transfers, authentication events, authorization events, and similar.

It should be in real time (or as close as possible).

I understand that there are various means for doing this manually via specific commands after the fact, but what I am trying to do is capture/follow events as they happen in real time.  Possibly streaming this information, though pulling it by tailing a log, or more likely various logs, would work as well.

Comment: What do you mean - like `top` (I learnt in the 1980s), or it's more modern counterparts (htop, glances, atop, iotop, iftop, ....... [it'd be a long list!])

Comment: This is a really broad request - you seem to be asking for a firehose of raw data as dozens of processes and ports wink in and out of existence constantly with a single users' normal usage quietly cruising the web. If you can explain what you want a bit more clearly, we may be able to offer better advice.

Comment: Well, yes actually.  That is what I am looking for.  A firehose of data.  Granted one that I will winnow down based on information I will be pulling from elsewhere.  I am currently looking at auditd but I am not convinced all of the information I am looking for will be there.  Also looking to direct that information to a data stream in parallel to or possibly even in place of it going to a file.  I'll be persisting it of/for my own purposes and there would be no need to burden the local machine with so much data.

Comment: @WTP How many processes do you want to track? Like one, or all of root, all of a user,  about 10 specific? Also, if you want to track 10 processes for example, do you want to track file accesses of all files used by them (which is tracked with the process anyway), or of all file accesses in the system?

Comment: Please do not close! The question, which I made more concise, actually is valid. And it has an answer which is pretty insightful. I'll try to answer it.

Comment: I want to track all of them.  I did find info, not sure why I had such a hard time finding it, on auditd/auditctl that appears to be able to give me what I'm looking for. Just getting back to this this morning so a quick cursory view it seems limited to tracking access to a file, for example, whereas I want to know all files that a process has touched.  I think auditd has what I am looking for and I may need to do some more googling based on what I now know but since this is already opened, I presume there is a way to stream this info to a process instead of a log?

Comment: So it looks like the AuditD logs will work for me but I'm having difficulty finding detailed information as to what some of the data means.  Just for example, consider:
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1530965821.126:2252): pid=4181 uid=0 auid=0 ses=34 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
not sure what the second msg (and why called msg when that is already a name/value name?) is about.  Really needing detail info on all 150 or so of these log messages.